# TheIntern.io/Selenium elementByCssSelector Only Works Once

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium

I'm having an odd issue where when I'm running a functional test via Selenium (using the Intern.io framework) only the first element is recognized; any element I attempt to access after returns an error of:

```
Error: Error response status: 7
```

I know this response resolves to:

```
{summary:'NoSuchElement',
detail:'An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.'}
```

This error is frustrating as I know the element is absolutely available.

Here is my simple functional test which is failing:

```
define([
  'intern!object',
  'intern/chai!assert',
  'require'
  ], function (registerSuite, assert, require) {
    registerSuite({
      name: 'search',

      'geocode search test': function () {
        return this.remote
        .get('http://localhost:8181')
        .elementByCssSelector('.modal-close').clickElement()
        .elementByCssSelector('#location_search_field').clickElement().type('San Francisco, CA')
      }
    });
});
```

The test will find the `.modal-close` element and click it appropriately, however, after it will return an error attempting to find the  `#location_search_field` element (throwing the error noted above).

If I comment out the `.elementByCssSelector('.modal-close').clickElement()` line, selenium has no issue finding the location input field and populating it with the string provided.

I've also tried the method `elementById('location_search_field')`.

If you're wondering about my environments array here is a copy of that:

```
environments: [
    { 
      browserName: 'firefox',
      platform: 'MAC',
      cssSelectorsEnabled: true,
      javascriptEnabled: true,
      applicationCacheEnabled: true,
      webStorageEnabled: true
    }
  ]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may have checked these already, but usual culprits include an element that's hidden away in a frame or iframe (you'll need to select the frame), or an element that's populated via dynamic scripts (you can set up an implicit or explicit wait).

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. Your hint led me to the answer although, it wasn't what I was expecting. I'll post what I found in odd case where someone else has my problem.

Comment: Handy! Appreciate you posting your solution. You probably won't be the only person who runs into that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thought I'd post the answer since I got it figured out. I've learned that as long as I add `.end()` after each browser action the test continues to run as I would expect it to.

Here's the updated code from my example:

```
define([
  'intern!object',
  'intern/chai!assert',
  'require'
  ], function (registerSuite, assert, require) {
    registerSuite({
      name: 'search',

      'geocode search test': function () {
        return this.remote
          .get('http://localhost:8181')
            .elementByCssSelector('.modal-close').clickElement()
              .end()
            .elementByCssSelector('#location_search_field').clickElement().type('San Francisco, CA')
      }
    });
});
```